# Is there a pythonic way to add conditions to while statements if variable is not None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to add a condition to a while loop, only if a variable value is not None.

This the approach I'm using right now:

```
from queue import Queue
max_limit = None  # could be None or an integer (user provided value)
q = Queue()
q = get_values()
counter = 0
while not q.empty() and \
      (not max_limit or counter <= max_limit):

     # If max_limit is None , counter <= max_limit never gets evaluated thanks to lazy OR

     # do stuff...
     counter += 1
```

The problem is right now it's very hard to figure out what is doing just by looking at it. Is there a more pythonic way to do that other than adding an if statement before or within the while loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite your statement:

> other than adding an if statement before or within the while loop

I believe that is actually the best solution.

It's likely to become a very ugly `while` condition if you ever end up with more than one of these constraints, so I would leave the `while` loop to handle the normal case and just add "exit loop early" code to handle the special cases, something like:

```
counter = 0
while not q.empty():
    counter += 1
    if max_limit is not None and counter > max_limit: break # User count limit.
    if GetElapsedTime() > timeLimit:                  break # Took too long.
    # Other checks as necessary.

    # do stuff...
```

With one exit reason per line (and documented), it still maintains the readabilty of the original loop.

---

You should keep in mind that Pythonic code isn't *always* the best code, sometimes it's used just for showing how clever people think they are :-)

My first inclination is to always optimise for ***readability.***

Comment: Nice - but note that OP explicitly states that `max_limit` my be `None`.

Answer (score 3):

Despite what your math teacher may tell you, there actually *is* a biggest number.

```
max_limit = # do something magic
if max_limit is None:
    max_limit = float('inf')
# ...
while not q.empty() and counter <= max_limit:
    pass
```

`float('inf')`, as the name implies, is the floating-point constant infinity, which is larger than any finite value. So it will effectively disable your condition, as `counter` will always be smaller. And the `while` loop code doesn't get kludged up with a bunch of conditionals either.

Comment: Despite what non-mathematicians may tell you, infinity is *not* a number, though some may debate that in a specific context (like finite-space representations such as IEEE-754). Those do not come into play in maths which can be assumed to have infinite space for storing numbers. It's well proven that there is no biggest number in that area, and I'm pretty certain that's the area math teachers should be working in :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
max_limit = None or sys.maxint  # use sys.maxsize for python 3
counter = 0
while not q.empty():
    if counter > max_limit:
        break  # exit the loop

    # do stuff...

    counter += 1
```

Comment: that's a valid alternative, but It's what I meant with 'other than adding an if statement before or within the while loop' in my original post.

Comment: Ah, I see - sorry, I missed that. IMO this is the best way (correct, concise, and readable), though if you're staunchly against an if statement there then YMMV. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
from queue import Queue
max_limit = None  # could be None or an integer (user provided value)
q = Queue()
q = get_values()
counter = 0
while q is not None and counter <= max_limit:

     counter += 1
```